# I want to share session among different sub domains in zencart

Tags: php, session, zen-cart

I am using zencart, I want to share session among deferent sub domains.
For example:

```
www.persun.com
fr.persun.com
de.persun.com
au.persun.com
```

they are using the same site files.
how to share same session among them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this, in order of preference

in php.ini:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".persun.com"
```

or in .htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .persun.com
```

or in script file(s):

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.persun.com' );
```